# Counting the cumulative sum of unique values in a vector

Tags: r, vector, statistics

Given a vector of length n, in which m unique elements exist, I want to count frequency of each m.

I've been able to do this using dplyr. My issue is that the output does not look simple enough.

```
vector <- (5, 3, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4, 1, 5, 5)
```

I would like the output to just be a vector with the cumulative sum of each unique element without actually specifying the element. For the example above it should just be: (2, 1, 2, 1, 4)

Comment: just `table(vector)` ?

Comment: or `tabulate(vector)` depending on what it is that you want.

Comment: `I want to count frequency of each m` , `table(m)` does that. `I would like the output to just be a vector with the cumulative sum of each unique element without actually specifying the element`, I don't know what this is?

Comment: the issue using table is that I am also returned a column with the unique values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). This is what I'm trying to hide. Sorry for not specifying!

Comment: *`vector <- c(5, 3, 3, 2, 5, 1, 4, 1, 5, 5)` for others. G. Grothendieck's answer should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `count`

```
library(tidyverse)
count(tibble(v1 = vector), v1) %>%
   pull(n)
```